# printing VML in IE8

Tags: javascript, printing, internet-explorer-8, vml

Here is a very simple VML sample which displays fine on all versions of IE. And it also prints on all versions of IE except IE8. I know that it is possible to make IE8 print VML, but can't find how I should do it. Thanks for any hint.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function ()
        {

            document.createStyleSheet().cssText = 'v\\:oval { behavior:url(#default#VML); display: inline-block}';                              
            document.namespaces.add('v', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml');

            var node = document.createElement("<v:oval>");
            node.style.width = "100px";
            node.style.height = "100px";                
            document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(node);  
        }

    </script>

    <div id="mydiv" style="background-color:#eeeeee; width: 800px; height: 620px;">
```

Comment: I noticed that removing doctype at all fixes this problem, however it's not a very good solution, as the my is widely used...

Answer (score 0):

You must add 3rd parameter to document.namespaces.add:

```
 document.namespaces.add('v', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml', '#default#VML');
```